# makefile, gcc, arm-cortex collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: gcc, makefile, linker, arm, cross-compiling

This makefile is autogenerated by STM32CubeMX. I am getting this linker error when I am using the arm-gnu-toolchain version > 9.2.1. I need to solve this problem. I cannot use the version in which the make is working fine because the openocd debugger is not compatible with arm-gnu-toolchain version 9.2.1

```
##########################################################################################################################
# File automatically-generated by tool: [projectgenerator] version: [3.13.0-B3] date: [Thu Mar 11 18:44:56 IST 2021] 
##########################################################################################################################

# ------------------------------------------------
# Generic Makefile (based on gcc)
#
# ChangeLog :
#   2017-02-10 - Several enhancements + project update mode
#   2015-07-22 - first version
# ------------------------------------------------

######################################
# target
######################################
TARGET = Testing_fes_bms


######################################
# building variables
######################################
# debug build?
DEBUG = 1
# optimization
OPT = -Og


#######################################
# paths
#######################################
# Build path
BUILD_DIR = build

######################################
# source
######################################
# C sources
C_SOURCES =  \
Core/Src/main.c \
Core/Src/freertos.c \
Core/Src/stm32l4xx_it.c \
Core/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_msp.c \
Core/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_timebase_tim.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_adc.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_adc_ex.c \
/Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_can.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_i2c.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_i2c_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_rcc.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_rcc_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_flash.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_flash_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_gpio.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_dma.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_dma_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_pwr.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_pwr_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_cortex.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_exti.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_tim.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_tim_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_uart.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_uart_ex.c \
Core/Src/system_stm32l4xx.c \
Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/croutine.c \
Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/event_groups.c \
Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/list.c \
Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/queue.c \
Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/stream_buffer.c \
Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/tasks.c \
Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/timers.c \
Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/CMSIS_RTOS_V2/cmsis_os2.c \
Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/MemMang/heap_4.c \
Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F/port.c \
BMS_OPERATION/BMS_OPERATION.c \
EXTERNAL_COMMUNICATION/USART_OPERATION.c \
AFE_OPERATION/AFE_OPERATION.c \
CAN_OPERATION/can.c

#===============================================#
#       ASM CONFIG          #
#===============================================#

# 433
#ASM_SOURCES =  \
#startup_stm32l433rctxp.s

# 431
ASM_SOURCES =  \
startup_stm32l431xx.s

#===============================================#


#######################################
# binaries
#######################################
PREFIX = arm-none-eabi-
# The gcc compiler bin path can be either defined in make command via GCC_PATH variable (> make GCC_PATH=xxx)
# either it can be added to the PATH environment variable.
ifdef GCC_PATH
CC = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)size
else
CC = $(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(PREFIX)size
endif
HEX = $(CP) -O ihex
BIN = $(CP) -O binary -S
 
#######################################
# CFLAGS
#######################################
# cpu
CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m4

# fpu
FPU = -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16

# float-abi
FLOAT-ABI = -mfloat-abi=hard

# mcu
MCU = $(CPU) -mthumb $(FPU) $(FLOAT-ABI)

# macros for gcc
# AS defines
AS_DEFS = 

#===============================================#
#       C DEFINE            #
#===============================================#

# 433
#C_DEFS =  \
#-DUSE_HAL_DRIVER \
#-DSTM32L433xx

# 431
C_DEFS =  \
-DUSE_HAL_DRIVER \
-DSTM32L431xx

#===============================================#


# AS includes
AS_INCLUDES =  \
-ICore/Inc

# C includes
C_INCLUDES =  \
-ICore/Inc \
-IDrivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc \
-IDrivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy \
-IMiddlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/include \
-IMiddlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/CMSIS_RTOS_V2 \
-IMiddlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L4xx/Include \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Include \
-IAFE_OPERATION \
-IBMS_OPERATION \
-IEXTERNAL_COMMUNICATION \
-ICAN_OPERATION


# compile gcc flags
ASFLAGS = $(MCU) $(AS_DEFS) $(AS_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

CFLAGS = $(MCU) $(C_DEFS) $(C_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
CFLAGS += -g -gdwarf-2
endif


# Generate dependency information
CFLAGS += -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)"


#===============================================#
#       LINKER CONFIG           #
#===============================================#

# 433
#LDSCRIPT = STM32L433RCTXP_FLASH.ld

# 431
LDSCRIPT = STM32L431CBTx_FLASH.ld

#===============================================#

# libraries
LIBS = -lc -lm -lnosys 
LIBDIR = 
LDFLAGS = $(MCU) -specs=nano.specs -T$(LDSCRIPT) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) -Wl,-Map=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections

# default action: build all
all: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).hex $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).bin


#######################################
# build the application
#######################################
# list of objects
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o)))
vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(C_SOURCES)))
# list of ASM program objects
OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(ASM_SOURCES:.s=.o)))
vpath %.s $(sort $(dir $(ASM_SOURCES)))

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR) 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.s Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(AS) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS) Makefile
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    $(SZ) $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.hex: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(HEX) $< $@
    
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.bin: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(BIN) $< $@    
    
$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir $@        


#flash: build/Testing_fes_bms.bin
#   st-flash write build/Testing_fes_bms.bin 0x8000000
#   python3 reader_python.py

#######################################
# clean up
#######################################
clean:
    -rm -fR $(BUILD_DIR)
  
#######################################
# dependencies
#######################################
-include $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/*.d)

# *** EOF ***
```

This is the error I am getting

```
PS C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN> make
arm-none-eabi-gcc build/main.o build/freertos.o build/stm32l4xx_it.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_msp.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_timebase_tim.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_adc.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_adc_ex.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_can.o build/stm32l4xx_hal.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_i2c.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_i2c_ex.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_rcc.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_rcc_ex.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_flash.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_flash_ex.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_gpio.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_dma.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_dma_ex.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_pwr.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_pwr_ex.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_cortex.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_exti.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_tim.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_tim_ex.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_uart.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_uart_ex.o build/system_stm32l4xx.o build/croutine.o build/event_groups.o build/list.o build/queue.o build/stream_buffer.o build/tasks.o build/timers.o build/cmsis_os2.o build/heap_4.o build/port.o build/BMS_OPERATION.o build/USART_OPERATION.o build/AFE_OPERATION.o build/can.o build/startup_stm32l431xx.o -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -specs=nano.specs -TSTM32L431CBTx_FLASH.ld  -lc -lm -lnosys  -Wl,-Map=build/Testing_fes_bms.map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections -o build/Testing_fes_bms.elf
c:/users/syedk/downloads/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/stm32l4xx_it.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/BMS_OPERATION/BMS_OPERATION.h:136: multiple definition of `QUEUE_bmsqueue_handler'; build/main.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/BMS_OPERATION/BMS_OPERATION.h:136: first defined here
c:/users/syedk/downloads/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/BMS_OPERATION.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/BMS_OPERATION/BMS_OPERATION.h:136: multiple definition of `QUEUE_bmsqueue_handler'; build/main.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/BMS_OPERATION/BMS_OPERATION.h:136: first defined here
c:/users/syedk/downloads/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/USART_OPERATION.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/BMS_OPERATION/BMS_OPERATION.h:136: multiple definition of `QUEUE_bmsqueue_handler'; build/main.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/BMS_OPERATION/BMS_OPERATION.h:136: first defined here
c:/users/syedk/downloads/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/USART_OPERATION.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/EXTERNAL_COMMUNICATION/USART_OPERATION.h:65: multiple definition of `USART_RX_Queue_Data'; build/main.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/EXTERNAL_COMMUNICATION/USART_OPERATION.h:65: first defined here
c:/users/syedk/downloads/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/USART_OPERATION.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/EXTERNAL_COMMUNICATION/USART_OPERATION.h:64: multiple definition of `USART_TASK_handler'; build/main.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/EXTERNAL_COMMUNICATION/USART_OPERATION.h:64: first defined here
c:/users/syedk/downloads/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/USART_OPERATION.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/EXTERNAL_COMMUNICATION/USART_OPERATION.h:59: multiple definition of `USART_RX_st_tag_Obj'; build/main.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/EXTERNAL_COMMUNICATION/USART_OPERATION.h:59: first defined here
c:/users/syedk/downloads/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/AFE_OPERATION.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/BMS_OPERATION/BMS_OPERATION.h:136: multiple definition of `QUEUE_bmsqueue_handler'; build/main.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/BMS_OPERATION/BMS_OPERATION.h:136: first defined here
/11.3.1/thumb/v7e-m+fp/hard\libc_nano.a(libc_a-writer.o): in function `_write_r':/data/jenkins/workspace/GNU-toolchain/arm-11/src/newlib-cygwin/newlib/libc/reent/writer.c:49: warning: _write is not implemented and will always fail
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:225: build/Testing_fes_bms.elf] Error 1
```

This is line 225 where the error is occuring

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS) Makefile
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    $(SZ) $@
```

Comment: what c library are you using? and where did you include it in the build. looks like you are missing the backend

Answer (score 1):

At last, after a month I was able to resolve this issue. The error was resolved once I solved the following errors

```
c:/users/syedk/downloads/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/stm32l4xx_it.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/BMS_OPERATION/BMS_OPERATION.h:136: multiple definition of `QUEUE_bmsqueue_handler'; build/main.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/BMS_OPERATION/BMS_OPERATION.h:136: first defined here
c:/users/syedk/downloads/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/BMS_OPERATION.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/BMS_OPERATION/BMS_OPERATION.h:136: multiple definition of `QUEUE_bmsqueue_handler'; build/main.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/BMS_OPERATION/BMS_OPERATION.h:136: first defined here
c:/users/syedk/downloads/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/USART_OPERATION.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/BMS_OPERATION/BMS_OPERATION.h:136: multiple definition of `QUEUE_bmsqueue_handler'; build/main.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/BMS_OPERATION/BMS_OPERATION.h:136: first defined here
c:/users/syedk/downloads/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/USART_OPERATION.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/EXTERNAL_COMMUNICATION/USART_OPERATION.h:65: multiple definition of `USART_RX_Queue_Data'; build/main.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/EXTERNAL_COMMUNICATION/USART_OPERATION.h:65: first defined here
c:/users/syedk/downloads/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/USART_OPERATION.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/EXTERNAL_COMMUNICATION/USART_OPERATION.h:64: multiple definition of `USART_TASK_handler'; build/main.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/EXTERNAL_COMMUNICATION/USART_OPERATION.h:64: first defined here
c:/users/syedk/downloads/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/11.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: build/USART_OPERATION.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/EXTERNAL_COMMUNICATION/USART_OPERATION.h:59: multiple definition of `USART_RX_st_tag_Obj'; build/main.o:C:\Users\syedk\Downloads\FES_BMS-v1.5.3_CAN\FES_BMS-v1.5.2_CAN/EXTERNAL_COMMUNICATION/USART_OPERATION.h:59: first defined here
```

The issue seems to be that the variables defined in header files need the extern keyword. If the header is included by several files it results in multiple definitions of the same variable. In previous GCC versions, this error is ignored. From GCC 10 a linker error will be reported. Hence the reason why the code was not getting compiled in arm toolchain version > 9